# JPA Entity mapping with no foreign keys available

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0, toplink, jdeveloper

I dont really get to work with entity beans, but they are staring at me right now.

We have a couple of tables that are related to each other, but there are no foreign keys, and we cannot add any. For this question, the database cannot change, it's just not possible, but as a different solution we might create views.  Anyways...

I have 3 tables.
LOCATION , LINKS and ENDPOINT and for extra salt, we a a LINKS_TYPE table.

LOCATION table has a primary key LOCATIONID which is a string containing the location id.

LINKS table has a LINKID as primary key
      a column LINK_ATTR_VALUE_A which contains ENDPOINT's primary key
      a column LINK_ATTR_VALUE_B which contains LOCATION's primary key.
      a column LINKTYPEID which contains a LINKS_TYPE primary key

ENDPOINT table has a primary key POINTID

LINKS_TYPE has primary key LINKTYPEID
    a column LINKTYPEA (text string defining the table name it's linked to)
    a column LINKTYPEB (text string defining the table name it's linked to)

Now even though LINKS_TYPE is mentioned, I dont need to worry about that now, because there are no other links in this instance of the database.

I would like to define a member in my LOCATION entity 'List endPoints'
Which would be a @OneToMany from my understanding.
Do keep in mind, there is no foreign key to help here, and there wont ever be.

This is the mapping I defined...

```
@OneToMany ( cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable ( name = "ENDPOINT",
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn ( 
                                name = "LINK_ATTR_VALUE_B"
                            ),
             inverseJoinColumns = 
                            @JoinColumn ( 
                                name = "LINK_ATTR_VALUE_A"
             )
            )
private List<EndPoint> endPoints;
```

It's very likely from this you might realize I have no clue what I'm doing :D
But the documentation aint too great, and Ive ordered a book for help with ejb 3, but I just dont have the time to finish the book before this mapping :D

We are using TopLink with jdeveloper 11g and that weblogic server thing and oracle 10g as database.

When using a serviceFacade client to query, everything did seem right (since then workspace died and I have to recreate the project to get the client working).
It generates the perfect query in my opinion to retrieve the right data. 
Yet, it ends with no results.

I'm willing to give as much info as possible, just not sure what is needed.
But I know my mapping is most probably wrong, and it's because I do not understand the mapping.

Could someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **LINKS** table looks like many-to-many mapping table between **LOCATION** and **ENDPOINT** rather than one-to-many. The big question here is whether it has any additional columns aside from `LINKID`, `LINK_ATTR_VALUE_A` and `LINK_ATTR_VALUE_B` that you listed?

If it does, then you would have to map it as a separate entity:
 `Location` would have a collection of `Links` mapped as bi-directional one-to-many
 `Link` would have many-to-one relationships with both `Location` and `EndPoint`

If, OTOH, **LINKS** has no other columns **AND** you're willing to forgo its primary key (which is neither needed nor can be mapped for many-to-many join table) then you can map it as many-to-many collection of `EndPoint`s on `Location`.

If you can clarify your question I'll update my answer to include the actual mapping if you need it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be trying some of your suggestions, if I'm still stuck I'll draw up lovely diagrams and all that jaz and post it here :D thanx

Comment: ok I was atlast succesfull mapping out our whole datamodel.
I will update this with how I did it... just need to do some admin now.

I select your post as the answer because it explained the valid options that I had available, as well as the concept that I needed to understand. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mapping I ended on.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "LINK",
    joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="LINK_ATTR_VALUE_B")
        },
           inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="LINK_ATTR_VALUE_A")
           }
)
private List<EndPoint> endPoints;
```

There just isnt truly any values needed right now in the **LINK** table.
But when it' time, our DBA's will need to create materialized views for us or something.

But when attemting the mapping, I initialy kept the **LINK**, rather than going straight to the **endPoint**. I was being returned 5000+ links where there should only be 133. So again there is a mapping I dont understand,but I'll leave that for later.

At the moment our database only contains 1 link type. This will change, and **I really which there was a way for me to add an additional where clause to the mapping**, so I could have different attribute mappings for different types.

I'm in a typing mood today :-D

Comment: You should change the above mapping to ManyToMany. Once you do that, the "where clause" will implicitly be added for LINK_ATTR_VALUE_B.
OneToMany is for things like Folder / Files where given file belongs to only one folder; whereas ManyToMany example is Author / Book where book can be written by multiple authors and author can write many books. ManyToMany ALWAYS requires a join table (e.g. Location / EndPoint has Link in between), OneToMany MAY have it but usually doesn't.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definately try that out :D